# SSIS Script Task get row count of csv files

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm using VS 2012 \ SQL SSIS.  How do I retrieve the row counts of records in csv files and assign them to a variable (RowCount) to be use later in the process?  I would also need to exclude 1 from the count as this will be the column header.

However, I cannot just use a Data Flow Task, OLE Source then a Row Count as I do not know the filenames (or headings of the csv's).  All I know is there will be at least row header.  So far I have a FOR EACH LOOP Container that looks into a specific folder and then assigns the filename to a variable "FileNameFound".  How do I configure the Script Task to then assign the RowCount to Variable "RowCount"?

[image]

So far in my Script Task (C#) I have tried the below just to test with a message box

```
public void main()
{
        string strPath = Dts.Variables["FileNameFound"].Value.ToString();
        string[] strArr = File.ReadAllLines(strPath);
        //MessageBox.Show(strArr[0]);
        MessageBox.Show("Total Records " + strArr.Length.ToString());

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

How do I assign the records counted to the SSIS Variable "RowCount"?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your Script Task code to find out what's going on - don't use `MessageBox` to debug.

Comment: strArr.Length-1

Comment: Do you really need to count all the rows or do you just need to know that there is at least one row beyond the initial header line? In the event you have a massively large file, the ReadAllLines could consume all available memory especially if you have a poorly provisioned machine.

Comment: Also, I'm a touch confused by `I cannot just use a Data Flow Task, OLE Source then a Row Count as I do not know the filenames` Could you help me understand the limitations in the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do I assign a value to an SSIS variable in a script task?

Assuming you have a variable named @[User::RowCount] in the Script Task configuration page, it has a place to identify the ReadOnly collection of variables as well as the Read/Write collection of variables. Add this to the ReadWrite collection.

In your actual code, you will assign the computed row count to the `.Value` property of an SSIS variable.

```
Dts.Variables["RowCount"].Value = strArr.Length -1;
```